Called to Office Without a Formal Offer Letter and told to bring my physical documents—Is This a Red Flag?
Brief about me:
I'll give my brief 1st I'm a core engineering grad in India. I passed out 3 yrs back, worked for 1 yr in digital field and then tried my hand in IT field after aquiring a professional diploma course certificate and thus when I couldn't cut it due to low hiring and GPT impact on IT industry I decided to come back to my core field for jobs which is my strong suit as I hold a degree in this, which was also one of the drawbacks why I couldn't cut it in software field, not holding a conventional degree in software field
THE ISSUE:
So recently I was selected for an internship by the HR telling me so verbally and asking me as well that will I be ready to accept it at 15k INR per month for 3 months and I verbally agreed that yes I'll be ready for the internship
so after 3 days or so of the above call, instead of what I hope is the standard procedure which is to send me the internship offer letter with the details of whatever was our agreement, this time I get a call(on a saturday evening 4PM around) from the person(sub senior maybe) that had interviewed me asked me the some details here and there to throw me off the real crux of his intention to call me, when he later said that they want me to come at office on Monday at 9 AM with all my physical documents and certificates the list of which would be mailed to me by the HR along with the internship letter, but he said that in case I don't get the mail, that was the reason he was letting me know to bring the documents
PS: do let me know if I left out some details that you all need to give a judgement on this. Let me know if you need any more details
something just doesn't sit right with me, I've given a lot of interviews and this was nowhere the standards followed
I felt it was downright rude to call me directly in the office like I'm a kid or something, that too without an internship letter, trying to take advantage of my situation is all, but at least do it within reason and with reasonable class
Opinion:
They want me to come to office on verbal agreement terms, where they'll i guess will present me the internship offer letter and the maybe get me to sign it.
Needless to say I'll make poor decisions if made to hurry the decision to sign, which is exactly what they want seemingly
PS: do let me know if I left out some details or something that you didn’t understand that you all need to give a judgement on this. Let me know if you need any more details?
LATEST QUICK UPDATE:
I had messaged the company people, if I could get the offer letter before me travelling to the company
In resoponse:
I recieved a call from the company saying no offer letter was sent due to our verbal agreement happening on a friday, thus there was not enough time to send me an offer letter and thus I'll be directly given my appointment letter on the same day as my joining

Where in the world are you? For example, where I live it is very common for "smaller" (less then "thousands of employees") companies to have you come by and sign contracts in person, instead of mailing copies and waiting for the mail to go back and forth. A written contract is mandatory, and the only way you start working on Monday would you have to come in and sign the contract. But maybe it's complete different where you live?

"I couldn't cut it in software field, not holding a conventional degree in software field" - no, that's not the case. There are many factors about the person that affect suitability for software development, and studying a degree does not alter them.

@nvoigt: given that the salary is 15k, I assume it's not the US or Euro-land, otherwise I really want that internship too :-)

@nvoigt I live in Maharashtra, Inidia. Where are you from
also the reason why this directly calling me to office behavior is suspect is beacause he said, in case HR doesn't send you mail for the offer letter either she would or she won't . What is this, may or may not, are we playing games here or are we professionals

@Steve I'm aware Steve that is the case generally, however that was the scenario I faced mostly in my diploma institute placements and I'm aware that is not the case generally in the open market, however I've felt and this is my own observation that companies find it much more safe and secure to bet on a conventional IT graduate than an non IT one, If I were in their shoes I would do the same ngl.

@Hilmar it's 15K INR haha

QUICK UPDATE:
I had messaged the company people, if I could get the offer letter before me travelling to the company
In resoponse:
I recieved a call from the company saying no offer letter was sent due to our verbal agreement happening on a friday, thus there was not enough time to send me an offer letter and thus I'll be directly given my appointment letter on the same day as my joining

Why are you accepting internships with 4+ years of professional experience?


I felt it was downright rude to call me directly in the office like I'm a kid or something

On the information given, it's a very bizarre reading of the situation to say the employer has been rude, or infantilised you, by merely asking you to come in to sign documents at short notice.
You don't have to accept the request of course. You can ask for more time, or ask for the information to be emailed before proceeding to sign them in person.
Perhaps rushing you is some kind of ploy, but sometimes employers do just want to get things done quickly or haven't allowed time to make preparations, and sometimes they want people to turn up in person just to check they are seriously in the running.

Or in short: Hanlon's Razor

thanks for a balanced view, it does help some
which country are you from btw, just asking as we natives sense shit when we see some natives try to do us

Relax. Having papers signed in person on the first day in the office isn't all that unusual especially for an internship.

Go to the office, bring all your stuff and see what happens. Expect the best, be prepared for the worst.
Do NOT sign anything without carefully reading it first.
If there is something in the paperwork you don't understand ask about it and/or ask for more time to review it. "Sorry, I need to look this over in more detail tonight and then I can sign it tomorrow".
If they push, push back. "Sorry, I don't sign anything that I haven't fully read or don't fully understand. I want to make sure I can keep all my commitments to you so I need to know what they all are".
Don't waver on that. It is absolutely acceptable (and commendable) to fully read before you sign. If that's a deal breaker for the company, so be it. That's not a company you want to work for.


Relax. Having papers signed in person on the first day in the office isn't all that unusual especially for an internship
Which country are you from, but I'm not sure if it happens this way in India in the core engineering jobs/internship sector ?
why I'm suspect is, he just said come to office at 9AM with physical documents and certificates but failed to mention the reason for the same. Like joining, document verification,offer letter singing it there is such a thing thing or anything like really. Am I sounding too prude in this situation, I don't know

@learningForever: Look either you go and see what happens or cancel and lose the job for sure. Worry about the problems when they actually occur.

while i can always do that, the reason for this post is to save travelling time as I currently can't spare much time and the job location is a bit far away

This may or not be a red flag.  But there is something you can do.  Draft a "memorandum of understanding".  You can send this by email before you go.
In the email, you're going to state the provisions of whatever verbal offer was made to you.  Be specific.  At the end of the email, ask the receiver to confirm that the terms agree with the verbal offer by giving a clear, concise  response to your email.  If you can't get a timely response, this is a red flag.
If there's any fallout when you finally get to the office, then you can fall back on this document.  If they're looking to change terms in a way that doesn't benefit you, you might consider greener pastures elsewhere.
